# Why did Azure pipelines suddenly stopped appearing in PR on GitHub (open source, public)?

Tags: github, azure-pipelines

I am using the free tier (though open source) of both Github and Azure pipelines. I am doing a C# boot camp and there are several active students making a few dozens weekly PRs. Normally, everything works, build is run on every new PR. However, today I see that none of the checks get triggered. Has anyone had any similar issues? What could be wrong?

Here is an example that illustrates no checks being done, regardless of pipelines being there and integration to azure installed:
https://github.com/csinn/CSharp-From-Zero-To-Hero/pull/222

P.S. I made no changes to the pipelines in the past month.

Comment: I'm not sure it is the same issue, but the azure CI pipeline is also failing to run for [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) pull requests.  It looks like they stopped running within the last day or so.

Comment: Likewise at [scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy).

Comment: They did mention moving away from certain environments and that the builds would be failing. However, I am using the latest windows vm, I don't think that one is problematic.

Comment: FYI: https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/179641421

Comment: Hi @Almantasm Are you still experience this issue?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks for the heads up. At least I know it's not entirely my end and there are a few things to try out to fix it. I probably won't to edit all the yaml...

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT yes, I just tried making a new PR and I don't have any checks information. However, I don't see Codacity check either...

Comment: Hey guys! Checked again today and all the checks are back :)